# How do I raise the mob capacity of my enderman farm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

How do I raise the mob capacity of my enderman farm?

I am several hundred blocks from the end island. However, I have only observed 24 entities at maximum. Near the end island, the mob cap is normal, but it drops when I go out into the void. Note that I am on a server.

How do I get the game to consider more chunks so the formula will give me the normal 70-some mob cap?

Comment: Are there other players in the end? What enderman farm design are you using? Is the server modded?

Comment: No, there were no other players in the end at the time of my using it. The server is not molded, and I am using docm77's endearment design. I also am somehting lkike 350-400 blocks out form land.

Comment: Do you have any under water caves or such ? Or is there a water leakage or something? As ender men hate water

Answer (score 1):

I believe the setting you are looking for is under game rules: maxEntityCramming. Adjusting this value should allow you more than 24 in a space. You can edit this through the chat if cheats are enabled, otherwise you will have to edit your game file.

Comment: you could also increase the space where the endermen are crammed in, or add vines to the walls to avoid max entity cramming.

Answer (score 0):

The server.properties files affects how your server behaves. The setting that affects monster spawning on a vanilla server is spawn-monsters, it can either be on or off. The setting view-distance affects how many chunks the server will push your way, but I don't believe this affects monster spawn rate. Default is 10, setting it higher may increase server lag.

Answer (score 0):

if you're playing on a miltiplayer server, the mobcap might be taken up by other players on the server. you can use spigot or bukkit plugins to increase the mobcap i believe.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a silverfish farm (an enderman farm with a silverfish in minecart in the middle) then I don't know. But if it is just normal then add a silverfish. If you need help with a silverfish using grinder look up a cube SMP video. (First season I think.)